# oracle query balance

Tags: sql, database, oracle, analytics

I want to select the balance of the last 2 days(today and yesterday) which the code look something like this

```
select a.balance as "today",b.balance as "yesterday"
from account a,account b
where a.id='xxx'
and a.id=b.id
and a.dates=to_date(sysdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY') --today
and b.dates=to_date(sysdate-1, 'DD-MM-YYYY') --yesterday
```

the problem came when the data for today has not been inputted yet.
this result the two balance null even though yesterday data is available

note: my current solution is to split the query into 2. but i am hoping there is any ways to use only 1 query

expected output

```
-----------------
|today|yesterday|
-----------------
|null |9000     |
-----------------
```

Data

```
--------------------------
|id   |balance  |dates   |
--------------------------
|1    |9000     |6/5/2015|
--------------------------
```

Comment: So what is your desired result in such situation?

Comment: @user2891092, sample data, expected output ?

Comment: the query still return the yesterday's data even when today's data is not available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to join two tables ,if we are allowed to hard code two dates

```
--code with sysdate 

with tab as  --dummy data
(
select 1 id,sysdate -level+1 dat,level*1000 balance 
from dual 
connect by     level <=10  
)
--main query
select max(decode(trunc(dat),trunc(SYSDATE),balance)) "today"
      ,max(decode(trunc(dat),trunc(SYSDATE-1),balance)) "yesterday"
from tab t where TRUNC(t.dat) IN (TRUNC(SYSDATE),TRUNC(SYSDATE-1));

--code without sysdate

with tab as
(
 select 1 id,sysdate -level dat,level*1000 balance 
 from dual 
 connect by level <=10
 )
 --main query
 select max(decode(trunc(dat),trunc(SYSDATE),balance)) "today"
      ,max(decode(trunc(dat),trunc(SYSDATE-1),balance)) "yesterday"
from tab t where TRUNC(t.dat) IN (TRUNC(SYSDATE),TRUNC(SYSDATE-1));
```

[sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/326)

```
select 
 max(decode(trunc(dates),trunc(SYSDATE),balance)) "today"
,max(decode(trunc(dates),trunc(SYSDATE-1),balance)) "yesterday"
from account a
where a.id='xxx'
and trunc(a.dates) IN (trunc(sysdate),trunc(sysdate-1));
```

Answer (score 3):

No need to join, use `LAG` function to track previous.
If you would like to know about Lag function. Please visit below link. 
http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/lag.php.
I have taken below as input.  [image]

and executed below query using lag which automatically tracks previous row.

`SELECT * FROM(
SELECT ID,LAG(BALANCE) OVER (ORDER BY DATES) AS YESTERDAY_BALANCE,BALANCE AS TODAYS_BALANCE
FROM ACCOUNTS)
WHERE YESTERDAY_BALANCE IS NOT NULL;`

Output which I got is below. If you wont get data for today still it will display the row.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking for yesterday OUTER JOINED onto today.

```
select a.balance as "today",b.balance as "yesterday"
from account a,account b
where b.id='xxx'
and a.id(+) =b.id  -- <----Here
and a.dates(+)=to_date(sysdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY') --today
and b.dates=to_date(sysdate-1, 'DD-MM-YYYY') --yesterday
```

I'm a bit rusty on that old syntax,  In more modern parlance

```
select a.balance as "today",b.balance as "yesterday"
from account b LEFT OUTER JOIN account a on
a.id=b.id and a.dates=to_date(sysdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY') --today
where b.id='xxx'
and b.dates=to_date(sysdate-1, 'DD-MM-YYYY') --yesterday
```

Notice how I've moved the checking of the optional table (a) to the join condition so it comes across anyway.

Comment: the query still return nothing when today data is empty

Comment: Sorry but without access to Oracle, your tables or your data, this is the best I can do.  It will be something along these lines, I assure you.

Comment: @user2891092 What about the join condition on ID? would it be same for yesterday's and today's balance?

Comment: It's going to be something to do with the dates not lining up exactly or if you've used chars instead of dates.  This works: a.id=b.id and to_char(a.dates, 'DD-MM-YYYY')=to_char(b.dates-1, 'DD-MM-YYYY') where you convert the values to chars but you really don't want to do that, you want to stick with actual dates.

Comment: @pratsam yes, the id for today and yesterday would be the same. the pk for the table is id+dates

Comment: when the data for today and yesterday is available, the code runs perfectly. so i dont think it is about the dates not lining up @LoztInSpace but instead using a decode function maybe?